# SQLite Find amount of stocks using data from different tables

Tags: database, sqlite

I have the following data structure shown in the picture and the task is to find the number of shares for each client. 
In the table deals, I have a column called euro_amount which has positive numbers if the client has sold some stocks or negative in case of buying.
I have to calculate the total number of shares the client holds.
My idea was to group deals by clients, then for every deal separately check if the euro_amount is positive, if yes then divide by sell_price(get a positive number), else divide buy buy_price(get a negative number) (from table prices). Then sum up the total amount of stocks.

But I am struggling with implementing it.
What I have tried is:

```
select *,
case when d.euro_amount<0 then (d.euro_amount/p.buy_price) as stock_in
else (d.euro_amount/p.sell_price) as stock_out
(stock_in+stock_out) as sum
inner join prices p on p.id_price=d.id_price
end
from table deals d
group by d.id_client;
```

I am getting an error: **Error: near "as": syntax error**
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: @Mureinik yes, the error is: Error: near "as": syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the 3 tables, `group by client` and aggregate with a `CASE` expression that meets your requirement:

```
select c.id_client, c.first_name, c.last_name,
  sum(d.euro_amount / case when d.euro_amount > 0 then p.sell_price else p.buy_price end) totalsum
from clients c
left join deals d on d.id_client = c.id_client
left join prices p on p.id_price = d.id_price
group by c.id_client, c.first_name, c.last_name
```

To avoid integer division, if the columns `euro_amount`, `sellprice` and `buy_price` are integers, use this:

```
  sum(1.0 * d.euro_amount / case when d.euro_amount > 0 then p.sell_price else p.buy_price end) totalsum
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!
Can you please explain the logic behind using sum and totalsum, why using sum only is not enough?

Comment: `totalsum` is just the name/alias of the column. SUM() is the aggregation function that returns the value of this column.

Comment: You can change `totalsum` to any name yoy like.

Comment: Sorry, one more question, maybe you know how to output stock names as well, in case if one client holds two different stocks?
Currently, I am only getting one name

Comment: Stocks is not involved in this query. You must join it too. But this query returns only 1 row for each client. How do you want all the stock names presented?

Comment: I wanted to join strings holding stock_name into one using concat and did something like this: select group_concat(concat(s.stock_name,s.stock_name)) group by s.stock_name)as stock_name

but got an error :no such function: concat

Comment: SQLite does not support the function concat(). Instead if you want to concatenate 2 strings use the operator `||` like: `string1 || string2`.

Comment: Can you please take a look, still getting an error:  

select c.first_name,c.last_name,
   ...> (select s.stock_name || s.stock_name  from stocks group by s.stock_name),
   ...>   sum((-1.0)*d.euro_amount / case when d.euro_amount > 0 then p.sell_price else p.buy_price end) totalsum
   ...> from clients c
   ...> left join deals d on d.id_client = c.id_client
   ...> left join prices p on p.id_price = d.id_price
   ...> left join stocks s on s.id_stock = p.id_stock
   ...> group by c.first_name, c.last_name;

Comment: Replace: `(select s.stock_name || s.stock_name from stocks group by s.stock_name)` with: `group_concat(distinct s.stock_name)` but joining another table to the query may (or may not) affect the totals.